# How can implement the function to count the frequency of that word in the text in percentage

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, word-frequency

**I want a function that calculates how often a given word occurs in a text, and expresses the result as a percentage. I want to read from fail and then return the frequent word with percentage.**

```
import re


words = re.findall(r"\w+", text)
frequencies = most_common(words)
percentages = [(instance, count / len(words)) for instance, count in frequencies]

for word, percentage in percentages:
    print("%s %.2f%%" % (word, percentage * 100))


NameError: name 'most_common' is not defined
```

I'd like to pass any word to the function and the function will count the frequency of that word in the text file

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
from collections import Counter


def frequency_in_text(word, text):
    words = re.findall(r"\w+", text)
    total_len = len(words)

    frequencies = dict()
    for string, freq in Counter(words).items():
        frequencies[string] = freq / total_len * 100

    return frequencies.get(word)
```

Comment: how can I print it? and I want to read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `pandas.Series.value_counts()` method:

```
import pandas as pd

def word_counter(text):
    words = pd.Series(re.findall(r"\w+", text))
    frequencies = words.value_counts(normalize=True)
    return frequencies
```

Comment: I use google collaborator, and I want to read from the file.

Comment: This works in google colab – just `import pandas as pd` @Rona

Comment: can you write all?

Comment: Let me revise to make it a function... @Rona

Comment: I want that calculates how often a given word occurs in a text, and expresses the result as a percentage.

Comment: This works. Try the code @Rona. Please keep in mind of the SO policies on how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).